# Error: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm using the Soft Actor-Critic implementation available [here](https://github.com/pranz24/pytorch-soft-actor-critic) for one of my projects. But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [256, 1]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 3; expected version 2 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).`

The error arises from the gradient computation in the `sac.py` file. I can't see the operation that might be inplace. Any help?

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-c124add9a61d> in <module>()
     22             for i in range(updates_per_step):
     23                 # Update parameters of all the networks
---> 24                 critic_1_loss, critic_2_loss, policy_loss, ent_loss, alpha = agent.update_parameters(memory, batch_size, updates)
     25                 updates += 1
     26 

2 frames
<ipython-input-7-a2432c4c3767> in update_parameters(self, memory, batch_size, updates)
     87 
     88         self.policy_optim.zero_grad()
---> 89         policy_loss.backward()
     90         self.policy_optim.step()
     91 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    196                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
    197         """
--> 198         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    199 
    200     def register_hook(self, hook):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     98     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     99         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
--> 100         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    101 
    102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just downgrade the PyTorch to anything under `1.5.0` (which is latest, as of writing this).

```
pip uninstall torch
pip install torch==1.4.0
```

Comment: Coincidentally, I'm getting this error after a PyTorch upgrade from 1.4 to 1.5. Is there a particular reason why 1.5 is raising this error, and does it reflect some actual problem in my code? (That is, if downgrading PyTorch just conceals an actual problem, then it's not a great solution.)

Comment: @mrwheet No idea what the actual issue is. `... does it reflect some actual problem in my code?` I highly doubt that. In my case, there were no problems in the actual implementation. In most of the other answers here and the GitHub, the code _actually_ had some inplace operation. But as I mentioned, I could find none. Another reason why I prefer using TensorFlow to PyTorch. ;)